# Exponential Diophantine $\prod x_i^{e_{x_i}} + \prod y_i^{e_{y_i}} = \prod z_i^{e_{z_i}}$ ,$e_{x_i}>3,e_{y_i}>3,e_{z_i}>3$

Tags: diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory

Does the exponential diophantine equation

$$ \prod x_i^{e_{x_i}} + \prod y_i^{e_{y_i}} = \prod z_i^{e_{z_i}}$$

with $x_i, y_i,z_i$ coprime and $e_{x_i}>3,e_{y_i}>3,e_{z_i}>3$ have solutions?

Any solution will give a good $abc$ triple. After browsing the list of $abc$ triples I did not find a solution in the list. Any heuristics?

*Update* nonsense relating conic to the $abc$ [triple](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/?set=2) $7^2+2^{17} 181^2=3^8 809^2$ deleted as pointed out by several commenters.

Ideas about searching for solutions?

Comment: Of course, your last equation has infinitely many solutions, take $y=t=1$ and the rest a primitive pythagorean triple.

Comment: Thank you Gjergji. Edited the question disallowing $\pm 1$

Comment: For any fixed y and t this is still a rational curve and has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Taylor thank you. Added "integer" solutions, coprime was in the OQ.

Comment: @joro: The resulting conic curve is still homogenous, so there are lots of coprime integer solutions.

Comment: @J.C. Ottem Thank you! I think I begin understand the second equation. Strangely to me some conics gave abc triples with quality 1.2 - 1.3 so I wonder should I delete the second equation or rephrase it sanely for abc triples...

Comment: The question is whether the sum of two coprime 4-full numbers can be 4-full. The first 4-full numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A036967

Comment: @Gerry I couldn't find solution in the first 300 terms.

Comment: For 3-full the only solutions I found are: 271^3 + 2^3 * 3^5 * 73^3=919^3 and 
3^4 * 29^3 * 89^3 + 7^3 * 11^3 * 167^3=2^7 * 5^4 * 353^3